# Working with multiple database types

Tags: database, delphi, bde

I'm currently building a program that primarily uses ABSDatabase, however I am trying to return the alias list from a BDE configuration, I'm currently using the following code:

```
  Session.GetDatabaseNames(gvAliasList);
  Session.GetTableNames(gvAliasList[0], gvTableList);
```

This will only bring back the database name for the ABSDatabase set, how can I make it return the BDE alias'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve all BDE aliases by using this code:

```
uses DBTables;

procedure LoadAliases();
var
  CurrentAliases: TStringList;
begin
  CurrentAliases := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Session.GetAliasNames(CurrentAliases);
    ComboBox1.Items:= CurrentAliases;
  finally
    CurrentAliases.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Remember that BDE is deprecated by Embarcadero and not actively developed since many years ago.
Try to migrate to a more current database access library like DBX.